# Android Facebook SDK - Different Devices, Different Results

Tags: android, authentication, facebook-android-sdk, htc-android

I have hooked up the Facebook application.  I have a couple different devices to test on, and I'm getting different results.  So far, everything is working great with my Motorola Droid phone, but I get a different experience when it comes to running the same code on an HTC Flyer.  Basically, it leaves me stuck at the "Loading" screen with a black "Facebook" screen in the background.  My application never completes authentication.

I have been digging around on the web, and I found a post about proceeding through SSL errors, 
but this [solution](http://myunixworld.blogspot.com/2010/11/android-facebook-sdk-issue-fix-for.html?showComment=1294381258058_AIe9_BGDXca377UlwHOlEr_p3SJo12zdJuK42VkyQyYl2Gqsfx9VfB3w5QY1uqNULDAG_frHqG1hhcgBM1zRquKKCw9_dUIT9Zi38PWDCUdDYqSExi6CNZlNfp4TS4132UXnfwoLaNZ7uF7Tw-kvVMMGzG0QWdZiqE484x-7MLu9lvTNgtRbyNfcPdnh8mEWl7COb_xARXlkG0JcrylLGxt0X2xG62H_8QEwdxmbWA0-Dy1UkB5dmArXYRACe2iIibXU6vy6p-1kR2NcSHRpb0UiPujnTI92m_0KKIEZmB6WeQ5zVrJy9FL8saBsFv_bFoZ8Aq2nM9QyhgqYBIwnjamjTsB85YyPgrw0gMNnaBf7bA_STnhZA0PVUziGp3ghwvamKBoiEnh6oCGlptQAXwLKK1IDQS44V6_ZWim7vtuDSXu5Qj-SOHNuWdU7ttqwAhlwWIPAYIIlrXjHX7fSnUHv98ZOjSVFne93h8lnHhwpTjLMB7Wc-SI#c5442685186348999639)  that doesn't work for me.

I am officially frustrated and I am not sure how to explain the problem better.  I know my SSO keys are correct, because I have one device that is fully working with the Login Experience and one that doesn't.  I have searched the web and there hasn't been any working solutions that I could find.

stringa

Comment: This problem exists with the examples provided with the SDK.

Comment: onActivityResult is never called in this case.